# My app is rejected with Exception EXC_BREAKPOINT and Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5

Tags: swift

My App works fine when ad-hoc exported, but is rejected again and again after submitting on App Store at the time of login.

Login Code:

```
    import UIKit
    class LoginViewController: BaseViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var mobileTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func loginButtonClicked(sender: UIButton) {

        if validateTextFields() {

            //       NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("devicseToken") as! String

     //Enable this to run over deivce


            if UIDevice.currentDevice().name.hasSuffix("Simulator"){
                //Code executing on Simulator
                let parameter = ["mobile": self.mobileTextField.text!, "password": self.passwordTextField.text!, "manager": "all" , "device_id":"asdad" ,"device_type":"I"]
                   print(parameter)
                   self.doLogin(parameter)
            } else{
                //Code executing on Device
                let parameter = ["mobile": self.mobileTextField.text!, "password": self.passwordTextField.text!, "manager": "all" , "device_id":NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("deviceToken") as! String ,"device_type":"I"]
                    print(parameter)
                self.doLogin(parameter)
            }


        }
    }

    func validateTextFields() -> Bool {

        if mobileTextField.text == nil || mobileTextField.text == "" {
            self.showAlertViewWithMessage(StringHeader.kApp_Name, message: StringHeader.kEnter_name)
            return false
        }
        else if passwordTextField.text == nil || passwordTextField.text == "" {
            self.showAlertViewWithMessage(StringHeader.kApp_Name, message: StringHeader.kEnter_Password)
            return false
        }
        return true
    }


    func doLogin(parameters: [String: AnyObject]) {

        if  !UserManager.sharedManager().isConnectedToNetwork()
        {

            self.showAlertViewWithMessage("LifeHover", message: "No internet Connection")

        }
        else
        {


        self.view.showLoader(mainTitle: "", subTitle: "")


        UserManager.sharedManager().performLogin(parameters) { (success, error, responseDate) -> (Void) in
            self.view.hideLoader()
            if success {

                let bookViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(String(AboutVC)) as?  AboutVC
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(bookViewController!, animated: true)

            }
            else {

                if let e = error {
                    self.showAlertViewWithMessage("LifeHover", message: (e.localizedDescription))
                }
                else {
                    self.showAlertViewWithMessage("LifeHover", message: ("Incorrect Username Password Combination"))
                }

            }
        }
        }
    }
```

Crash Report:

```
Incident Identifier: 253AE2BD-9966-4F60-AB55-08E6F579160F
CrashReporter Key:   84c4ae66fc00683964b8061ca97c78e5e795a8c4
Hardware Model:      iPad5,4
Process:             LifeHover [390]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E72F562-949C-47BB-9A18-CF94A1231443/LifeHover.app/LifeHover
Identifier:          com.App.LifeHoverPush
Version:             3 (1.2)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.App.LifeHoverPush [432]


Date/Time:           2016-12-19 05:58:30.4270 -0800
Launch Time:         2016-12-19 05:58:24.7426 -0800
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.1.1 (14B100)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000001000b1a84
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   LifeHover                       0x00000001000b1a84 0x100040000 + 465540
1   LifeHover                       0x00000001000afff8 0x100040000 + 458744
2   UIKit                           0x000000018c8b7484 0x18c872000 + 283780
3   UIKit                           0x000000018c8b7404 0x18c872000 + 283652
4   UIKit                           0x000000018c8a18b8 0x18c872000 + 194744
5   UIKit                           0x000000018c8b6cf0 0x18c872000 + 281840
6   UIKit                           0x000000018c8b6818 0x18c872000 + 280600
7   UIKit                           0x000000018c8b1a60 0x18c872000 + 260704
8   UIKit                           0x000000018c88252c 0x18c872000 + 66860
9   UIKit                           0x000000018d06fa54 0x18c872000 + 8378964
10  UIKit                           0x000000018d0694bc 0x18c872000 + 8352956
11  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001869dc278 0x1868ff000 + 905848
12  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001869dbbc0 0x1868ff000 + 904128
13  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001869d97c0 0x1868ff000 + 894912
14  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186908048 0x1868ff000 + 36936
15  GraphicsServices                0x000000018838e198 0x188382000 + 49560
16  UIKit                           0x000000018c8ed2fc 0x18c872000 + 504572
17  UIKit                           0x000000018c8e8034 0x18c872000 + 483380
18  LifeHover                       0x00000001000eaf78 0x100040000 + 700280
19  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001858ec5b8 0x1858e8000 + 17848

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001859fea88 0x1859df000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185ac2178 0x185ac1000 + 4472
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185ac1da4 0x185ac1000 + 3492

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001859fea88 0x1859df000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185ac2178 0x185ac1000 + 4472
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185ac1da4 0x185ac1000 + 3492

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185ac1da0 0x185ac1000 + 3488

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001859e016c 0x1859df000 + 4460
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001859dffdc 0x1859df000 + 4060
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001869dbcec 0x1868ff000 + 904428
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001869d9908 0x1868ff000 + 895240
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186908048 0x1868ff000 + 36936
5   Foundation                      0x0000000187419a8c 0x18740d000 + 51852
6   Foundation                      0x000000018743a57c 0x18740d000 + 185724
7   UIKit                           0x000000018d262a2c 0x18c872000 + 10422828
8   Foundation                      0x000000018751747c 0x18740d000 + 1090684
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185ac4850 0x185ac1000 + 14416
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185ac4760 0x185ac1000 + 14176
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185ac1dac 0x185ac1000 + 3500

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001859fea88 0x1859df000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185ac235c 0x185ac1000 + 4956
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185ac1da4 0x185ac1000 + 3492

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185ac1da0 0x185ac1000 + 3488

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x000000000000000b   x3: 0x0000000170246900
    x4: 0x000000000000000b   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x00000001ab27bd20   x9: 0x0000000000000000  x10: 0x000001a1ab280ac1  x11: 0x000000160000003f
   x12: 0x000000015a86d500  x13: 0x000021a1ab280ac1  x14: 0x0000000000000000  x15: 0x024ac3b0b2feadcf
   x16: 0x000000018548248c  x17: 0x0000000185482e90  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000159f29a50
   x20: 0x0000000159f43210  x21: 0x00000001ab281f88  x22: 0x0000000159e24540  x23: 0x0000000100bf17e8
   x24: 0x0000000159e06010  x25: 0xa003635343332316  x26: 0x000000017404dc80  x27: 0x0000000170246900
   x28: 0x0000000000000040   fp: 0x000000016fdbda60   lr: 0x00000001000b1374
    sp: 0x000000016fdbd9b0   pc: 0x00000001000b1a84 cpsr: 0x60000000

Binary Images:
0x100040000 - 0x10049bfff LifeHover arm64  <f9db3a5e01e63c1396bac3c5a9ba759e> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E72F562-949C-47BB-9A18-CF94A1231443/LifeHover.app/LifeHover
0x100654000 - 0x100683fff dyld arm64  <f5a894bbb0cc38b1930add2172007394> /usr/lib/dyld
0x1006d8000 - 0x1006effff ActionSheetPicker_3_0 arm64  <728196da1817344db549beae14d9a8af> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E72F562-949C-47BB-9A18-CF94A1231443/LifeHover.app/Frameworks/ActionSheetPicker_3_0.framework/ActionSheetPicker_3_0
0x100714000 - 0x100773fff Alamofire arm64  <4c12b3a21e39324c9a5e6c11f7f06798> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E72F562-949C-47BB-9A18-CF94A1231443/LifeHover.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
0x100858000 - 0x100863fff HCSStarRatingView arm64  <c83e91501de539cd986f29f9a0043890> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E72F562-949C-47BB-9A18-CF94A1231443/LifeHover.app/Frameworks/HCSStarRatingView.framework/HCSStarRatingView
0x100874000 - 0x10087ffff HSDatePickerViewController arm64  <c7b8d6fb6b0f365ba73d9e58b62c88b6> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E72F562-949C-47BB-9A18-CF94A1231443/LifeHover.app/Frameworks/HSDatePickerViewController.framework/HSDatePickerViewController
0x100894000 - 0x1008d3fff IQKeyboardManagerSwift arm64  <2e372c096ff9352594f824b53bda2cc6> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E72F562-949C-47BB-9A18-CF94A1231443/LifeHover.app/Frameworks/IQKeyboardManagerSwift.framework/IQKeyboardManagerSwift
0x10094c000 - 0x10095bfff MBProgressHUD arm64  <d0b107212db432d5be6b96cc41300b8c> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E72F562-949C-47BB-9A18-CF94A1231443/LifeHover.app/Frameworks/MBProgressHUD.framework/MBProgressHUD
0x100970000 - 0x10097bfff Pulsator arm64  <cc7254f9a61437fb96164604d0e86ffd> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E72F562-949C-47BB-9A18-CF94A1231443/LifeHover.app/Frameworks/Pulsator.framework/Pulsator
0x100994000 - 0x10099bfff Reachability arm64  <bda06ff7f7ed38b5969afa22742a1abc> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E72F562-949C-47BB-9A18-CF94A1231443/LifeHover.app/Frameworks/Reachability.framework/Reachability
0x1009ac000 - 0x1009b3fff libswiftAVFoundation.dylib arm64  <f70e80c8fa0233cf899f384731da2a05> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E72F562-949C-47BB-9A18-CF94A1231443/LifeHover.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib
0x1009c0000 - 0x100bbffff libswiftCore.dylib arm64  <160a815885033b4db08d3aa94ac06413> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E72F562-949C-47BB-9A18-CF94A1231443/LifeHover.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
0x100df4000 - 0x100dfffff libswiftCoreAudio.dylib arm64  <58a8f57aca863149aebdbac2305cbf5e> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E72F562-949C-47BB-9A18-CF94A1231443/LifeHover.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreAudio.dylib
0x100e10000 - 0x100e17fff libswiftCoreData.dylib arm64  <cd552930672d3d3b8e49da0d7f57b889> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E72F562-949C-47BB-9A18-CF94A1231443/LifeHover.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreData.dylib
0x100e24000 - 0x100e2ffff libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib arm64  <c685370568a7357a892b4d3a6988cf1a> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E72F562-949C-47BB-9A18-CF94A1231443/LifeHover.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
0x100e44000 - 0x100e4bfff libswiftCoreImage.dylib arm64  <2844310aca6b3065b95998a211349d0e> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E72F562-949C-47BB-9A18-CF94A1231443/LifeHover.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib
0x100e54000 - 0x100e5bfff libswiftCoreLocation.dylib arm64  <fa035a31cc593657b06b9f74b301a27c> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E72F562-949C-47BB-9A18-CF94A1231443/LifeHover.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreLocation.dylib
0x100e68000 - 0x100e6ffff libswiftCoreMedia.dylib arm64  <8cca1ee9fb8630708c7e292e67e9bfcb> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E72F562-949C-47BB-9A18-CF94A1231443/LifeHover.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreMedia.dylib
0x100e7c000 - 0x100e83fff libswiftDarwin.dylib arm64  <5bba14fccdf032e28baa867a05052262> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E72F562-949C-47BB-9A18-CF94A1231443/LifeHover.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib
0x100e94000 - 0x100e9bfff libswiftDispatch.dylib arm64  <824a17f74200332b829d35895e9082ec> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E72F562-949C-47BB-9A18-CF94A1231443/LifeHover.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib
0x100ea8000 - 0x100ee3fff libswiftFoundation.dylib arm64  <82511703757935b5896edf3a94c1e4f6> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E72F562-949C-47BB-9A18-CF94A1231443/LifeHover.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib
0x100f30000 - 0x100f37fff libswiftObjectiveC.dylib arm64  <56af7ca1e2e635ee8273bef66ff0c119> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E72F562-949C-47BB-9A18-CF94A1231443/LifeHover.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
0x100f48000 - 0x100f53fff libswiftUIKit.dylib arm64  <6355134b558732ce8e34790dc6145970> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E72F562-949C-47BB-9A18-CF94A1231443/LifeHover.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib
0x100f60000 - 0x100f67fff libswiftContacts.dylib arm64  <a6629800411534029d5fe5e53b462ec4> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E72F562-949C-47BB-9A18-CF94A1231443/LifeHover.app/Frameworks/libswiftContacts.dylib
0x1853e4000 - 0x1853e5fff libSystem.B.dylib arm64  <7f6df0ff83ca38c5bd2451d798c6619b> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x1853e6000 - 0x18543bfff libc++.1.dylib arm64  <ad5eb3d0e134370ab9ab52e3979ac239> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x18543c000 - 0x18545cfff libc++abi.dylib arm64  <514938651ad43466908d2d993b588bec> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x185460000 - 0x185839fff libobjc.A.dylib arm64  <cfe85583868931d48088e908339f76c6> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x18583a000 - 0x18583efff libcache.dylib arm64  <3f13f51a773b35c1ba38ca66ad803e89> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x18583f000 - 0x18584afff libcommonCrypto.dylib arm64  <dc02b342926033248c75ef323b51edc4> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x18584b000 - 0x18584efff libcompiler_rt.dylib arm64  <6bcab91bf9f1390eac1d038f9a2699d6> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x18584f000 - 0x185856fff libcopyfile.dylib arm64  <0c337bd80f193fbdb28313e4eaf758ea> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x185857000 - 0x1858b7fff libcorecrypto.dylib arm64  <3b0c9c05a798360ebc821fbe2f50b95c> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x1858b8000 - 0x1858e7fff libdispatch.dylib arm64  <3840477f1dcb32c5be29d805a0b43d93> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x1858e8000 - 0x1858ecfff libdyld.dylib arm64  <39aaa2dbe1a1313c9c838cc0268a2ea0> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x1858ed000 - 0x1858edfff liblaunch.dylib arm64  <04e27dee99a031ba8a7124b6b72c909c> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x1858ee000 - 0x1858f3fff libmacho.dylib arm64  <a3797232763a393faa9bf3cf5a871e0c> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x1858f4000 - 0x1858f5fff libremovefile.dylib arm64  <28e912626c483873a21e720a9e6e31d3> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x1858f6000 - 0x18590dfff libsystem_asl.dylib arm64  <36b03a6fe92b36a687a31254e4eef33b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
0x18590e000 - 0x18590efff libsystem_blocks.dylib arm64  <1c111df9108e3d0f90cfbe5a197ae4a2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x18590f000 - 0x18598dfff libsystem_c.dylib arm64  <93efa69c71cb30a092cc72cf178f2e65> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x18598e000 - 0x185992fff libsystem_configuration.dylib arm64  <e57ff277342c3b22b2da2fecef617b23> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
0x185993000 - 0x185998fff libsystem_containermanager.dylib arm64  <41d8a1a4127b3cccb4cb93f337b922d7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_containermanager.dylib
0x185999000 - 0x18599afff libsystem_coreservices.dylib arm64  <5f536aa39a3d34079d3277708c4b5f3b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
0x18599b000 - 0x1859b3fff libsystem_coretls.dylib arm64  <5b2a44a2d8ed3cc6aaccbae99e805dd4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coretls.dylib
0x1859b4000 - 0x1859bafff libsystem_dnssd.dylib arm64  <dd0a055b1bea35e7a371d2a134aa4cb4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x1859bb000 - 0x1859defff libsystem_info.dylib arm64  <b372a8a239223d20b9cb13bd4efe0790> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x1859df000 - 0x185a03fff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64  <3bb31dbc99853fa4b33f4948c9e2af64> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x185a04000 - 0x185a30fff libsystem_m.dylib arm64  <03779efeda81345586b8fd3d69323160> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x185a31000 - 0x185a4cfff libsystem_malloc.dylib arm64  <2828f6cf98c631969e22ae3aaf0c9289> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
0x185a4d000 - 0x185aa4fff libsystem_network.dylib arm64  <5e487af9f3a03dd8ba7833602b554363> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x185aa5000 - 0x185aaefff libsystem_networkextension.dylib arm64  <db6affcb13a53af58cbe796b7ef935bd> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
0x185aaf000 - 0x185ab9fff libsystem_notify.dylib arm64  <a86d8c5a0bea3666a69ecfc6b81a2fe7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x185aba000 - 0x185ac0fff libsystem_platform.dylib arm64  <14630f9a42813c0a819764b8ada8383b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
0x185ac1000 - 0x185acafff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64  <548d3d6a3b5738f2820e0382c8d77c0e> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x185acb000 - 0x185acefff libsystem_sandbox.dylib arm64  <4bb12da1ae923ba38e60e63ced4c0ad0> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x185acf000 - 0x185ad6fff libsystem_symptoms.dylib arm64  <295884acb7c63956892540ada2cd23a4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib
0x185ad7000 - 0x185af5fff libsystem_trace.dylib arm64  <8c79d49939f33d33b5a29474667934b8> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
0x185af6000 - 0x185afbfff libunwind.dylib arm64  <f4dc6306fe0d3a819f67667eff14553c> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x185afc000 - 0x185afcfff libvminterpose.dylib arm64  <027cf263be4933609dd97728b329a18b> /usr/lib/system/libvminterpose.dylib
0x185afd000 - 0x185b23fff libxpc.dylib arm64  <a0c4e91da2c839b59ecbbb7aa397e244> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x185b24000 - 0x185d3efff libicucore.A.dylib arm64  <e53c0577ce0b38afb83a2b7a54b4a390> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x185d3f000 - 0x185d4ffff libz.1.dylib arm64  <a8ab1654147738bda28160886a3a5df1> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x1868ff000 - 0x186c82fff CoreFoundation arm64  <d72e357f5b3337aa9693522564a6032e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x186c83000 - 0x186c93fff libbsm.0.dylib arm64  <a964c720dd6c3b828b3490d0da04b5f8> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x186c94000 - 0x186c94fff libenergytrace.dylib arm64  <e6230b7a7ea4327893377cb661336e25> /usr/lib/libenergytrace.dylib
0x186c95000 - 0x186d10fff IOKit arm64  <97df8046f49d3a3c9a28ad1c89ec90a9> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x186d11000 - 0x186d31fff libMobileGestalt.dylib arm64  <e9c324bb1aa63739946642d6cf3c2dd0> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x186d32000 - 0x186e1cfff libxml2.2.dylib arm64  <30ee067a18313bb18a3ad40b0dd4ccc1> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x186e1d000 - 0x186eaafff Security arm64  <0e0e9f42cb41335ab94eee731c6a4db8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x186eab000 - 0x186f15fff SystemConfiguration arm64  <d2744fb1dcd93a0e938f5065e7ac4039> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x186f16000 - 0x18702afff libsqlite3.dylib arm64  <a54037ad22f1329998d318a227192323> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x18702b000 - 0x18739bfff CFNetwork arm64  <516a98d92600361d89748c8c865aeb9d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x18739c000 - 0x1873acfff libbz2.1.0.dylib arm64  <4035caebd18030b698192b8c92fed3ea> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x1873ad000 - 0x1873c5fff liblzma.5.dylib arm64  <690a1d50cfad332c9ffce151555cf5d3> /usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
0x1873c6000 - 0x1873e0fff libCRFSuite.dylib arm64  <b80cb8a907773d08997be69dc6340070> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x1873e1000 - 0x18740afff libarchive.2.dylib arm64  <104744e9187837d8ba843c443f4a98cb> /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib
0x18740b000 - 0x18740cfff liblangid.dylib arm64  <70c15ad0050435899c857e8844aedd04> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x18740d000 - 0x1876dbfff Foundation arm64  <8c727aea9f34365fb2fe552669585011> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x1876dc000 - 0x187788fff libBLAS.dylib arm64  <6ea5b89378513f2e846e31871b410a0b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x187789000 - 0x187acbfff libLAPACK.dylib arm64  <0646b0c159c93102926cdf9221d11568> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x187acc000 - 0x187d6efff vImage arm64  <c17d2e052c6f36349a2cae4dd3a5aee1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x187d6f000 - 0x187d91fff libvMisc.dylib arm64  <20d445b170e730d1888141bfaa6be593> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x187d92000 - 0x187da6fff libLinearAlgebra.dylib arm64  <930cd329b8ea391fb226d14819375940> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
0x187da7000 - 0x187db8fff libSparseBLAS.dylib arm64  <2ee1252ee69e3ec587cc93364d05fd4d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libSparseBLAS.dylib
0x187db9000 - 0x187e31fff libvDSP.dylib arm64  <43133d90a9fd32e681cee537ebc0f154> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x187e32000 - 0x187e32fff vecLib arm64  <1b404e41514b383285c36288ece53c9b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x187e33000 - 0x187e33fff Accelerate arm64  <3c43596ee1eb3048a65bfc8b3bb05c0c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x187e34000 - 0x188381fff CoreGraphics arm64  <1b546c1bd4eb334eb850e116b430e550> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x188382000 - 0x188396fff GraphicsServices arm64  <6d8ec4c741ae3332ae4854a3c69f9c68> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x188397000 - 0x1883e2fff AppSupport arm64  <caf9b40929c73faeaaf25b33ad2a0647> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x1883e3000 - 0x188505fff MobileCoreServices arm64  <8172d8e133d23395bbfa078d6a44f089> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x188506000 - 0x18855dfff BaseBoard arm64  <b33d2bf343f43bc5b5a7d0d4b4dd5f5a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BaseBoard.framework/BaseBoard
0x18855e000 - 0x188569fff AssertionServices arm64  <7610246b4f683b77811d43811f30465d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssertionServices.framework/AssertionServices
0x18856a000 - 0x188596fff BackBoardServices arm64  <d463b45d03f13e6987eb6bdae3bf941c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x18859b000 - 0x1885eafff FrontBoardServices arm64  <c559fb4fa9ba31319bc7b1ba9c4ba308> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
0x1885ee000 - 0x188621fff SpringBoardServices arm64  <d388e2d75b523b748f195d9a3d27d278> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x188622000 - 0x188636fff MobileKeyBag arm64  <270099c5284b31a1906053816b6cec02> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x188637000 - 0x18863ffff IOSurface arm64  <ef7ac073d6943dc78d9fd3440e0348d9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x188640000 - 0x18864bfff liblockdown.dylib arm64  <9b0b0e6f40d33edfaf15399d4bad8121> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x18864c000 - 0x188661fff CrashReporterSupport arm64  <66e9fd41492333dfab588cc2021fbebc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x188662000 - 0x188664fff IOSurfaceAccelerator arm64  <4e2f4feb26af3b22ae56f1730fb8a133> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurfaceAccelerator.framework/IOSurfaceAccelerator
0x188665000 - 0x1886a5fff AppleJPEG arm64  <87de27bcf04536ae846760442b89cad1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleJPEG.framework/AppleJPEG
0x1886a6000 - 0x188c39fff ImageIO arm64  <e16442857870346fbe11e98073358914> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x188c3a000 - 0x188c40fff TCC arm64  <225b54db9ae3396fa00a310bf3310765> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
0x188c41000 - 0x188c45fff AggregateDictionary arm64  <5eae0ee54d7238d38c60df504164bd7c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x188c46000 - 0x188c52fff PowerLog arm64  <752721ed2da73535b1f7e61d50c0026b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PowerLog.framework/PowerLog
0x188c53000 - 0x188cbbfff libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib arm64  <878f4d0fcf5830a984dfecf58c639d0a> /usr/lib/libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib
0x188cbc000 - 0x188ccefff CommonUtilities arm64  <0d35a47331413981a51a592a4b4c3302> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x188ccf000 - 0x188ce3fff libcompression.dylib arm64  <388d583a262f3c8fbbb0453ff8d17426> /usr/lib/libcompression.dylib
0x188ce4000 - 0x188f7efff CoreData arm64  <8ed91a98ce0b37208579ff6ed712895c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x188f7f000 - 0x188f82fff libCoreVMClient.dylib arm64  <760ae35b9c1932edbd00150e7a98233a> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x188f83000 - 0x188f88fff IOAccelerator arm64  <89785d94951d32b1a745248a1bf25467> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator
0x188f89000 - 0x188f8afff libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib arm64  <5affde13a3443280a5965cd5348d5149> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x188f8b000 - 0x188f8efff libCoreFSCache.dylib arm64  <893e81d4d84e3946974e360cb29cda11> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
0x188f8f000 - 0x188fd2fff libGLImage.dylib arm64  <8b343c8b5c2537d08c7e1885354b1215> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x188fd3000 - 0x188fddfff libGFXShared.dylib arm64  <0058e13e9a2f382eb9cde69f36b7ff62>
```

Message By Apple:
Your app still crashed on an iPad and iPhone running iOS 10.2 connected to an IPv6 network when we:

1) Launch the app.
2) Enter in the provided demo account credentials.
3) Tap submit.
4) App crashes.

This occurred when your app was used:

- On Wi-Fi

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crash report so you can see the exact line of code causing the crash. No one can you until you do at least that much.

Comment: Do you have any idea now? I got the exact same `Exception Type` `Termination Signal/Reason/Process/Thread` when ad hoc release. And the weird thing is I can't duplicate this crash unless it's an iPhone that has never installed the app.

Answer (score 0):

Trace/BPT trap 5 is usually related to the missing shared libraries ([`.dylib` files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker)). Make sure your app has proper access to them and you have included them correctly along with your app.

You can use `otool` (`-L`) command-line tool to scan your app for any missing dependencies.